# DataTables - Getting the database ID of the current row via click event

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I am trying to get the database ID of the current row while clicking a button.

I have seen a few examples relating to this aspect and have tried many but it seems that they mostly relate to the legacy table tools extension whereas I am making use of the Editor.

Using the [idSrc](https://editor.datatables.net/reference/option/idSrc) option from the Editor manual I recieve a server side response in JSON that contains the databases id/primary key value:

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Test Name",
    }
  ],
  "options":[],
  "files":[]
}
```

Now I am trying to get that value by clicking a button that is attached to row via the API function: [row().id()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.id%28%29)

Within the example for this function it provides a clear example of how the rows id value (now the database id?) can be obtained:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
$('#myTable').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
  var id = table.row( this ).id();
  alert( 'Clicked row id '+id );
});
```

So I have implemented this as follows:

```
var editor;
$(document).ready(function() {

  editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: "/names.php",
    table: "#example",
    idSrc: "id",
    fields: [ {
      label: "Name:",
      name: "name"
    } ]
  });

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    ajax: "/names.php",
    columns: [
      { data: "name" }
    ]
  });

  $('#example').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var id = table.row( this ).id();
    alert( 'Clicked row id ' + id );
  });

});
```

The problem here though is that when I click on the row (tr) it prompts as follows: `Clicked row id undefined`

Why am I getting back an undefined value when it should be sending back the row id?

Comment: Is `table.row(this)` returning anything for you?

Comment: @silkfire Thx for the response, it returns `Clicked row id [object Object]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When instances your DataTable, you must indicate the id field `rowId`, which should be indicated as the name of your columns

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
dom: "Bfrtip",
ajax: "/names.php",
columns: [
  { data : "id" },//id is the name of your data
  { data: "name" }
],
rowId: 'id' //Here assign the id to your table
});
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/17/

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. I am not sure if this really solves the problem though as you require the id to be seen within the table data. In the `idSrc` documentation it mentions that "By default Editor will use the DT_RowId property from the data source object." and through the server side code this gets changed to simply `id`. So it's this ID that I want to return, I don't think it needs to be in the table for me to do that?

Comment: @CraigvanTonder check the reference of `rowId` http://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId . DataTables will attempt to automatically read an id value from the data source for each row using the property defined by this option `rowId`.

Comment: Thanks a heap, you're right about looking into the rowId docs. It seems that this is all that was needed for me to get the primary key into the id value of that row and from there it was easy enough to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

As @CMedina pointed out, `rowId` stipulates which value in the JSON data is used as each rows id attribute.

Here is the code used to get the rows ID value which is prefixed with `row_`:

```
$('#example').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
  // Get the rows id value
  var id = table.row( this ).id();
  // Filter for only numbers
  id = id.replace(/\D/g, '');
  // Transform to numeric value
  id = parseInt(id, 10);
  // So instead of returning the actual id which is row_1
  // We get back just the primary key which is 1
  alert( 'Clicked row id '+id );
});
```